# Windows 10 - EXCEL in M/S Office 365 Ver.:1708

Tags: microsoft-excel, links

How does one create a Link to the contents of a cell which changes cell locations.  FOR EXAMPLE:  I want to clink on a cell (Let's say cell H4) at the top of my Excel documents which contains the text "E-MAIL".  When I click on that, I am immediately taken to the Cell E2743 (which Contains the text "E-MAIL INFORMATION"), and directly below that cell is all the information I want to have available when I click on the original link.  Unfortunately, additional lines of information are constantly being added to all points of the document; therefore, the original cell of E2743 which contains the text "E-MAIL INFORMATION", will soon exist in cell E2867, and still later in cell E3126, and then still later possibly in cell E2974.  (I do not know whether to call this a floating link, a dynamic link, or a link that always changes.)
HELP!!!!
I am approaching my third anniversary in looking for an answer.  Continually re-labeling the links gets old, tedious and incredibly time consuming.
THANK YOU!
Linden Adkins

Comment: You would create a *hyperlink* to the destination cell.  The destination cell can be on he current sheet, or on a different sheet, or even a cell on a different workbook.  By assigning a **Name** to the destination, you can let it float.

Answer (score 0):

For example, say the content "E-MAIL INFORMATION" is somewhere on column **E**, but we don't know in which row.  In **H4** enter:

```
=HYPERLINK("#E" & MATCH("E-MAIL INFORMATION",E:E,0),"jump")
```

Clicking on **H4** will now cause the active cell to become the cell containing the content:

[image]

Comment: Very nice, GS. What's the purpose of the #, wouldn't it work with just "Ennnn" as the destination?

Comment: @Bandersnatch  It is simply the syntax to reference a cell address.